# Changing button style in a gridview on click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, buttonfield

i'm using a gridview filled with 7 buttonfields and 2 boundfields on each row.
I'm trying to change the backcolor of my buttonfield on each click and doing some db update with a sp.
I have tried to get that on rowcommand but having a null reference for the button object.
I've also tried to find some references to this subjetc but just found elements on templatefields with buttons inside and i'd like to use a buttonfield not a template one.

Here's a row sample of my gridview :

```
<asp:ButtonField DataTextField="datechg_1" HeaderText="Date chg 1" Text="Btn1" ButtonType="Button" CommandName="chgColor"></asp:ButtonField>
<asp:ButtonField DataTextField="datechg_2" HeaderText="Date chg 2" Text="Btn2" ButtonType="Button" CommandName="chgColor"></asp:ButtonField>
<asp:ButtonField DataTextField="datechg_3" HeaderText="Date chg 3" Text="Btn3" ButtonType="Button" CommandName="chgColor"></asp:ButtonField>
```

and here's the rowcommand code throwing null reference :

```
 protected void grid_date_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName=="chgColor")
            {
                Button btn = e.CommandSource as Button; << null reference here -_-                
                var color = btn.Style.Value;
                switch (color)
                {
                    case "background-color:red;":
                        btn.Style["background-color"] = "rgb(0,200,83)";
                        break;
                    case "background-color:blue;":
                        btn.Style["background-color"] = "rgb(242,101,34)";
                        break;
                    case "background-color:green;":
                        btn.Style["background-color"] = "rgb(229,57,53)";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

The switch color isn't good at all i guess, but it's not a problem at the moment. I would like to know how to get the button clicked.
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: instead of using asp:ButtonField you can use asp:TemplateField of gridview and create ItemTemplate then create asp:Button inside that and give CommandName in that

Answer (score 0):

Add OnRowCommand event to Gridview.

```
 <asp:GridView OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField />
        </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

and class

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
      //Response.Write(e.CommandArgument);        
 }
```

Comment: i already have a RowCommand for my gridview `protected void grid_date_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)`

Comment: you should divine it in your ButtonField aswell.